# One of the + In or Among

Tags: prepositions

I am not sure which one is correct.

> 1. He is one of the best thinkers **in** American authors.
> 2. He is one of the best thinkers **among** American authors.

Comment: Can  you say why you might think one of your alternatives might be better than the other?

Comment: I really confuse. Both two of them seem correct to me. @peter

Comment: The first one seems weird to me, while the second one sounds way better.

Comment: You can't be "*in* authors", right? If so, please explain.

Comment: One uses "in" to show location "in America", "in the world". "Amercian authors" is a group of people, so doesn't make much sense. You could say "He is one of the best thinkers *in America." which would make sense. "Among" means to be a part of and within a group, "He is among the crowd."

Answer (score 2):

As several of the commenters have noted, the prepositions don't match well in your first example, but match just fine in your second. While that answers the question that you ask, it's not going to be very helpful to you moving forward. So let's actually look at the prepositions and where each is going to make the most sense. And to make it fun, let's use some owls!

[image: Prepositions of Place]

As you can see by the owls, the preposition ***IN*** is most appropriate where what you're referring to can be placed within what you're describing. This is contrasted by ***AMONG***, which as you can see describes an individual element of a group.